# Display add to cart form / +product from node template

Tags: commerce

I have a custom node template based on a custom content type and I want to display products with their "Add to Cart" buttons from this custom node template.

In the content type (actually a field collection), I added the Product reference. In the template (node--{content type}.tpl.php) I do this type of thing:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
// Since it's a field collection, I loop these:
foreach ($wrapper->field_content_group as $group) {

  //Now each "$group" has the fields I want to display

  //I permit N products (not just 1), so I can get product information, 
  //like price for example, like this:

  if($group->field_featured_product) {
    $product_references = $group->field_featured_product->value();
    foreach($product_references as $product_reference) {
      $product = commerce_product_load(intval($product_reference->product_id));
      $price = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_product', 
                                       $product)->commerce_price->value();
      print $price_display = commerce_currency_format($price['amount'], 
                                                    $price['currency_code'], $product);
    }
  }

}
```

I don't need to alter the display, I'm happy with that. I'd like to just call something that prints the product, price, etc., along with the "Add to Cart" button. I'm thinking I call commerce_product_load and then some method(s) that gives me the completed form. Is there such a thing that I can call?

NOTE: Yes, I know about separation of concerns and that code is best placed outside of the template file.

Comment: I've got to ask - if you know it's good practice to separate logic and display, why would you ignore it? This logic should be moved out of the template file and into a preprocess function for all sorts of reasons, not just best practice. Caching for one.

Comment: Work in Process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since views seem to be the easiest way to display product offerings, the way I solved this was to create views for the products. The views are configured as blocks. Then I use:

```
$block = module_invoke('views', 'block_view', $block_name);
print render($block['content']);
```

to display the block.

I used content type fields to specify the block names I want to display within certain areas so it isn't hard-coded. It isn't terribly elegant, but sometimes programming is that way since there isn't an infinite amount of time to solve problems!

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate way of doing this, as shown by [duckzland](https://drupal.org/user/492890) on [drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/1232470):

**Note**: You may need to alter the product retrieval code slightly to match the way your node is set up. Using `var_dump($content)` should help you determine the structure.

Load your product through the node template, without calling `commerce_product_load()`:

```
<?php
$view['product'] = NULL;
// retrieve raw product from field containing your product's info
if(isset($content['product:field_featured_product']) { 
    $view['product'] = $content['product:field_featured_product'];
}
// do stuff to output the product here
// add to the cart here
// build the line items for shopping cart
$order_id = 0; // optional
$line_item = commerce_line_item_new($view['product']->type, $order_id);
$line_item->data['context']['product_ids'] = array($view['product']->product_id);
$line_item->quantity = 1;
// need to create config for quantity
$qty = 1;
$form_id = commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_id(array($view['product']->product_id), $qty);
$addtocart_form = drupal_get_form($form_id, $line_item);
// we alter the submit form to use our special theme function
// need to move this to configuration
$addtocart_form['submit']['#theme'][] = 'vtcommerce_button_small';
$variables['cart'] = render($addtocart_form);
```